# Does WHERE clause affect how MySQL locks a table?

Tags: mysql, deadlock

We are encountering deadlocks that at first glance doesn't make sense.
We have the following table:

`liveMember` (`id`, `memberID`, `liveID`, `dateUpdated`, `dateLeft`)

And we have a keep-alive endpoint in our application that constantly updates the `dateUpdated` column every 10 seconds.

Here is our `UPDATE` statement:

```sql
UPDATE
    `liveMember`
SET
    `liveMember`.`dateUpdated` = NOW()
WHERE 1
    AND `liveMember`.`liveID` = 139959
    AND `liveMember`.`memberID` = 3761423
    AND `liveMember`.`dateLeft` IS NULL
```

And this is a deadlock:

```sql
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2020-07-28 19:09:21 2b598948a700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 4555766560, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 3, locked 3
LOCK WAIT 4 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 3 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 116431423, OS thread handle 0x2b5b67943700, query id 1402103525 ---- et updating
UPDATE
    `liveMember`
SET
    `liveMember`.`dateUpdated` = NOW()
WHERE 1
    AND `liveMember`.`liveID` = 139959
    AND `liveMember`.`memberID` = 3761423
    AND `liveMember`.`dateLeft` IS NULL
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 170197 page no 1244 n bits 1160 index `liveID` of table `et_inevent`.`liveMember` trx id 4555766560 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 227 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 800222b7; asc   " ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80028bba; asc     ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 4555766561, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 3, locked 3
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 4 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 116431422, OS thread handle 0x2b598948a700, query id 1402103526 ------ et updating
UPDATE
    `liveMember`
SET
    `liveMember`.`dateUpdated` = NOW()
WHERE 1
    AND `liveMember`.`liveID` = 139959
    AND `liveMember`.`memberID` = 3761474
    AND `liveMember`.`dateLeft` IS NULL
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 170197 page no 1244 n bits 1160 index `liveID` of table `et_inevent`.`liveMember` trx id 4555766561 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 227 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 800222b7; asc   " ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80028bba; asc     ;;
```

Both updates belong to the same `liveID`, however, they should never update the same row since they use two different `memberID` values.

Would changing the order of our `WHERE` clause help our database detect that the lock should only be done on rows with that given `memberID`?

Am I missing something here?

Index table:
[image]

Result of `EXPLAIN`:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: The order of conditions in a `WHERE` clause shouldn't have any effect. The query planner decides the order that it checks conditions based on its estimate of which will have the best performance, e.g. it will prefer to use an index first.

Comment: Both columns are foreign keys

Comment: They may have different cardinality, which will inform the preference.

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see the query plan with the where clause rearranged, I don't think you'll see any difference.

Comment: Just added our indexes for this table

Comment: Maybe you can solve your problem by using the `FORCE INDEX` clause.

Comment: Would that ignore `liveID` index or only hint to prefer `memberID` index instead of `liveID`?

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html

Comment: Don't know if this would solve the issue, since it was using an index merge and only row locking the necessary rows, or am I wrong? When I use FORCE INDEX, the amount of rows on EXPLAIN increases drastically